# Apache Camel - IDLE AMQP1.0 Connection

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, connection

I have Apache-Camel with Spring application. Application acts as a bridge between two AMQP destinations. It consumes messages from one broker and publishes it on to the other broker. Communication is done both ways over AMQP1.0 protocol.

**Problem**
I am facing a IDLE connection issue. After few days of operations, the consumers stops receiving messages, unless restarted. Moreover, I am not able to get any ERROR logs. This issue goes away after restart of application.

My expectation is that similar to Spring-JMS, Apache Camel shall retry connecting the consumers. Kindly guide me if I need to configure something in Camel to perform reconnection tries and do proper logging.

**Camel Route COnfiguration**

```
        cmlCntxt.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("incomingOne:queue:" + inQueueOne)                     
                      .to("outGoingBroker:queue:"outQueueOne).transform(body().append("\n\n"));
            from("inQueueTwo:queue:" + inQueueTwo).to("outGoingBroker:"+outQueueTwo).transform(body().append("\n\n"));
        }
    });
```

Moreover I am not having control of the brokers at both ends and am unable to check why my consumers are not receiving messages. That is why I am expecting camel ERROR logs to be informative for me to debug the issue, whether connectivity or else.

Comment: The RabbitMQ component has `automaticRecoveryEnable` flag, maybe you can play with the [JmsConnectionFactory](https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/blob/master/qpid-jms-client/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/jms/JmsConnectionFactory.java) with `closeLinksThatFailOnReconnect`, see sample use [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/amqp/AMQPRouteTraceFrameTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring `jms.requestTimeout` property at your remoteURI. by default, the requestTimeout is indefinite . So incase of any issues, it might stuck forever.

Also try using failover to connect the broker and enable debugging in application.

if you are still facing the issue, kindly edit with broker details